# PdfKit doc.pipe() error

Tags: node.js, pdf, filesystems, fs, pdfkit

So in my code i have the following lines that work fine :

```
var newPdf = new pdfKit();
newPdf.pipe(fs.createWrtieStream('output.pdf'));
```

A file called output.pdf is created and stuff written into it! But the followings dosen't create a file :

```
var newPdf = new pdfKit();
var myString = 'output.pdf'
newPdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(myString));
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to end the line.
It should be this:

```
var newPdf = new pdfKit();
var myString = 'output.pdf';
newPdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(myString));
```